# Why first for statement is always for row and second for statement is for columns?

Tags: python-3.x

[python star printing program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O29hf.png)

it is a program to print star in python.My query is that why only first for loop statement is for rows and second statement is for columns?

Comment: Because that is how it logically outputs, the inner one outputs a row, and each letter in that row can be considered a column. The outer loop therefore iterates through the rows. You cannot first iterate through the columns because that is not how standard output works.

Comment: Because you must print an entire line (row) before moving to the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the ***logic***.

*columns are children of rows*. every element in the first loop, parents every element in the second loop therefore, always the first loop elements are the **rows** (**parents**), and the inner loop elements are **children** (**columns**).

you can change it by changing the order of loops.

Comment: because of the "logic"  haha
thanks for your answer